# number of labelled $n\times k$ bipartite graphs without cycles of length $4$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I would like to know the explicit formula for the number of labelled $n\times k$ bipartite graphs without cycles of length $4$.

Equivalently, the number of $n\times k\;$ $0/1$-matrices with the following condition:

Inner product of any two rows is at most $1$.

Motivation for this comes from [*Enumeration of 0/1-matrices avoiding some 2x2 matrices*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1299) by Ju and Seo.

Comment: Can you do a simpler problem, say, the number of labelled $n\times n$ bipartite graphs with no cycle of length 4?

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth noting that there are unsolved problems not far away from thhis question. In particular, there is the question, how many edges can such a graph have? Some bounds are known, but in general they are not known to be optimal. See this link on the [Zarankiewicz problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem). This suggests (but doesn't prove) that there may be no explicit formula for your question, or at least that it may be very hard to find one.

[Here](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~naor/homepage%20files/bipartite2k.pdf) is a paper that deals with the question of bounding the number of edges in such a graph.